# Beginner book that has endgame scenarios

Tags: endgame, books, beginner

I’ve been looking for free online books on endgame scenarios, since I'm very bad at them. So far, I haven’t gotten any luck.

By the way, I only know the pieces moves and some other basic stuff.

Comment: Your first step should be to look up to the left hand corner of this page where you will see "Search on Chess". Click there and enter "beginner learning book" and hit return and you will get a list of useful questions which have been asked before whose answers will tell you what you need to lonow

Comment: So, if I do that, what would stop me from finding non-online books, or paid books?

Comment: A good resource are studies on Lichess... all of them are free and some are designed in an interactive way. https://lichess.org/study feel free to search for whatever you desire: beginner, endgame basics, middlegame basics...

Answer (score 2):

BCE (Basic Chess Endings) by Fine was the one I used.  It is long out of print.  There are some  newer books but I can't say which of them might be good now.  Also online has the sort of info you want and would be easier to find what you think is good for you.